# Changing Whole Page Color via COM object

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I am trying to change the whole page color in MS Word using VBScript COM interface. But the code does not seem to work. I tried the following code:

```
Option Explicit

' Variables
Dim objDoc, objFile, objWord

' Create a Word object
Set objWord = CreateObject( "Word.Application" )

' Now Create a Document object
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

' make Word visible
objWord.Visible = True

' Set a default text
objDoc.Content.Text="Hello"

objDoc.Background.Fill.Visible = True
objDoc.Background.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(55, 255,155)

' Close the active document
'objDoc.Close

' Close Word
'objWord.Quit
```

(I also tried using luacom but abandoned due to its limitations!)

I am using Windows 8. Can anyone point what I am doing wrong... or the things are all different in Win8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the background color programmatically it's displayed only if you change the view type to *Online Layout*:

```
objDoc.Background.Fill.Visible = True
objDoc.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(55, 255, 155)
objDoc.Background.Fill.Solid
objWord.ActiveWindow.View.Type = 6
```

It'll be visible only in that layout, though, so this might be a bug.

On a more general note: please drop the habit of commenting the obvious. Comments shouldn't rephrase what the actual statement already clearly says, but illuminate the purpose of a statement or a group of statements when they are not so obvious.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Ansgar. Pls apologize me, English is my secondary language. Microsoft is concentrating on fancy and luring things only hence they forgot to test it.:|